# Creating a legend, and printing a graph with python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am wanting to add a legend to the graph below and download it as a pdf. The code I have for the graph is below.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mta = pd.read_csv('../project/all_mta_data_cleanded.csv') # mta data cleanded into similare catagories
cata = pd.read_csv('../project/mta_catagories_breakdown.csv') #document combining all of the catagories
weather = pd.read_csv('../project/New York Tempeture Data.csv')
mta['Total Lost Items'] = mta['Total Lost Items'] = (mta['Accessories']+ mta['Books'] + mta['Bags'] + mta['Cellphones'] + mta['Clothing'] + mta['Money'] + mta['Eletronics'] + mta['Entrainment'] + mta['Glasses'] + mta['Shoes'] + mta['Household Items'] + mta['Indentification'] + mta['Jewlery'] + mta['Keys'] + mta['Medical Equipment'] + mta['Miscellaneous'] + mta['Instruments'] + mta['NYCT Equipment'] + mta['Sports Equipment'] + mta['Tickets'] + mta['Tools'] + mta['Toys'] + mta['Wallets/Purses'])
clear = mta.iloc[[13, 40,68,92,115,138,157,176,200,222,241,245,246,250],:] #selected the last pull of each month
compl = pd.merge(clear,weather, left_on='Date',right_on='Time',how='outer').drop(columns=['Time'])
```

````
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()                                                  
ax1.plot(compl['Date'], compl['Temp'] ,color = 'red',marker='o')                                                                                            
ax2= ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(compl['Date'], compl['Total Lost Items'],color= 'purple',marker='^')
ax1.set_ylabel('Tempeture in Fahrenheit', )
for tick in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)
ax2.set_ylabel('Number Of Items Lost')
ax1.set_title('Average Weather In New Your City vs Total Items Lost Each Month')
plt.set_legend()
plt.figure.savefig('Project Figure.pdf')```
````

Answer (score 0):

to add a legend to your graph you have to specify the field "label" in plt.plot(), use plt.legend() and plt.show()

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
l1 = ax1.plot(compl['Date'], compl['Temp'] ,color = 'red',marker='o', label = 'label_1')    
ax2= ax1.twinx()
l2 = ax2.plot(compl['Date'], compl['Total Lost Items'],color= 'purple',marker='^', label = 'label_2')
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature in Fahrenheit')
for tick in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)
ax2.set_ylabel('Number Of Items Lost')
ax1.set_title('Average Weather In New Your City vs Total Items Lost Each Month')
plt.legend([l1,l2],['lab1', 'lab2'])
plt.show()
plt.savefig('Project Figure.pdf')
```

Comment: This helped some, but when I run the code I am only getting 'label_2' in the legend. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You have to change the field label in the .plot. As you can see, now it's 'label_1'.

Comment: when I tried running your code 'lable_ 1' does not appear in the legend only 'label_2'. I am unable to figure out how to fix this problem.